# Subclassing Django ListView

Tags: django, listview, generics, view

I'm using Django v1.4 and I'm trying to subclass the generic ListView view.  Here's the code

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class SearchListView(ListView):
    model = None
    fields = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        #...etc...
        return super(SearchListView, self).get_queryset()
```

Then I'll further customize that view for a particular model:

```
class PersonSearchListView(SearchListView):
    model = Person
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']
```

So what happens is, ImproperlyConfigured exceptions are the superclass (ListView) stating that either model or queryset should be defined.  I thought I was... (model = Person).  Why is this value not making it into the view?

Thanks

Comment: maybe you can try with removing the model = None and fields = None from the SearchListView. Could you post the code which instantiates the PersonSearchListView?

My guess is that when initializing PersonSearchListView it first calls the SearchListView constructor, but when it constructs the SearchListView the model is still None.

Comment: The code that instantiates the PersonSearchListView was in urls.py.  PersonSearchListView.as_view().  Turns out declaring models and fields in the SearchListView class was OK.  Actually, I have no idea what I did to make it work.  My code was riddled with comments of failed attempts.  I was trying to get it back to being inline with my above example code and all of a sudden it works.  I'm thinking I had a class name typo somewhere or a urls config problem.  :)

Comment: Yea keeping your code clean is important it will prevent lots of bugs and makes finding bugs easier. It will save you time in the longterm.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `super(SearchListView, self).get_queryset()`

You will call the get_queryset of the below class, as you can see it will raise an exception if you didn't set the model or queryset.

ListView is a child of MultipleObjectMixin.

But if you instantiate a PersonSearchListView, the model should have been set correctly. Could you include the url config? Will try it out later and update my answer.

```
class MultipleObjectMixin(ContextMixin):
    """
    A mixin for views manipulating multiple objects.
    """
    allow_empty = True
    queryset = None
    model = None
    paginate_by = None
    context_object_name = None
    paginator_class = Paginator

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Get the list of items for this view. This must be an iterable, and may
        be a queryset (in which qs-specific behavior will be enabled).
        """
        if self.queryset is not None:
            queryset = self.queryset
            if hasattr(queryset, '_clone'):
                queryset = queryset._clone()
        elif self.model is not None:
            queryset = self.model._default_manager.all()
        else:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("'%s' must define 'queryset' or 'model'"
                                       % self.__class__.__name__)
        return queryset
```